Loop through all GCP instance disks
I have a long list of instances in a GCP project. I want to create a small Ansible playbook that go through the instances, list all the disks attached to each instance, then find out the deviceName and the disknames (source), find out those that do not match (some disks were given a different deviceName when attached to the instance).
I can use Ansible module to find out the instance_info:
     22   - name: get instance info again
     23     gcp_compute_instance_info:
     24       zone: us-central1-a
     25       filters:
     26       - name = "{{ machine1 }}"
     27       project: production-project
     28       auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
     29       service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
     30     register: server_reg

and the disk part of the output from the register look like this:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "autoDelete": false,
        "boot": false,
        "deviceName": "test-server",
        "diskSizeGb": "100",
        "index": 1,
        "interface": "SCSI",
        "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
        "mode": "READ_WRITE",
        "source": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/stl-production-project/zones/us-central1-a/disks/test-server",
        "type": "PERSISTENT"
    }
}

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "autoDelete": false,
        "boot": false,
        "deviceName": "hahahaha",
        "diskSizeGb": "100",
        "index": 1,
        "interface": "SCSI",
        "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
        "mode": "READ_WRITE",
        "source": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/production-project/zones/us-central1-a/disks/test-data",
        "type": "PERSISTENT"
    }
}

The first disk has the deviceName and the source name matching, but the second one does not.
How do I create the playbook that can loop through all the disks attached to each instances as each instance will have different number of disks, then only display the deviceName and the source (the last string after the /).
Thanks!

There is not enough information to provide a full answer. Especially the input data structure and content are missing. Also there is no playbook and tasks shown. From the only example you are showing "display the devicename and the source (the last string after the /)", that would simply be the basename filter – get a path’s base name and "{{ server_reg.deviceName }}: {{ server_reg.source | basename }}" resulting into an output of msg: 'test-server: test-server'.

Regarding "find out those that do not match (some disks were given a different devicename when attached to the instance)" that could be when: server_reg.deviceName != server_reg.source | basename.

Thanks for the reply. One of my issue is how to loop through the output server_reg to find all the disks attached to the instance. The output I have above was using debug with parameters "{{ server_reg.resources[0].disks[0] }}" and "{{ server_reg.resources[0].disks[1] }}" as I know this instance has two disks. But other instance may have more or less disks.  I want to find how to loop through all the disks. Thanks!

Maybe you can update your initial question by editing and provide the full output of server_reg? Than it would be probably be possible to provide a better answer.

I found a way to loop through all the disks:
  - include_tasks: display_disk_info.yml
    vars:   
      disk_info: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ server_reg.resources[0].disks }}"

In the display_disk_info.yml, i can display the deviceName and the source name, and compare them.
Thanks!
